# How to find out what is shutting down my MacBook Air while closed?

Tags: macos, macbook-air, macos-highsierra

I have a 2011 MacBook Air running macOS High Sierra that keeps on shutting down while closed. I can't figure out what triggers that and would like pointers for things to check.

In more details, what happens is that I would close the laptop, leave it plugged in overnight and come back to it either completely off or showing a message telling me some program (e.g., iTerm2) preventing the laptop from logging out. When I turn it back on, the battery isn't empty.

I looked a bit if Console.app would show something but nothing obvious appeared. Admittedly, I don't know what to look for…

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you read through this discussion and similar? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115513/theres-a-change-what-happens-when-you-close-the-laptop-lid-setting-in-windows

Comment: Thanks for the link. I hadn't looked at this one, but sleeping is not the issue. I actually want the laptop to sleep. What I don't want is to be completely logged out.

Comment: Is it staying on, and then overheating?

Comment: I suppose overheating is a possibility. I'm fairly sure it does go to sleep, I will check that to be certain. (I know I would have noticed if I weren't asked for my password when opening the laptop for the times it doesn't shut down) It *is* common for the fans to continue blowing when closed, so something I need to dig into. Are there any logs somewhere if the laptop is overheating or similar?